# How do i create a human readable datediff in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a timestamp that represents the last time a particular record was viewed. I want to present to the user a display that gives a human readable representation of the difference between that time and now.

So it should be something like

"Last viewed 38 seconds ago"

or "Last viewed 1 hour 15 minutes 10 seconds ago"

Is there a quick way to do this in rails?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[distance_of_time_in_words](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words), or [dotiw](http://github.com/radar/dotiw) (allegedly better)